# log search using hadoop

Tags: search, hadoop, mapreduce

We have huge log files(~ 100s of Gigs) on multiple web servers that are needed to be searched in real time. These log files are written multiple times/second by different apps. We have recently installed a hadoop cluster on some servers for this purpose. In order to implement search on these logs, I have thought of this design: there is a process running on web servers which creates an inverted-index of logs and cache it in-memory (on web servers itself) and push to HDFS via flume to be stored in Hive when  the cache is full (this is much like an LRU cache). This helps in two ways when something is searched for: most recent logs are returned from in-memory cache and is fast and older logs are returned from disk. And since user wants to see latest logs first, this technique works. Can somebody verify if this design will work and scale properly. Are there any better alternatives around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the inverted index in HBase to provide more real-time access to your older logs.

HBase would also likely be a viable alternative to your in-memory cache. You could do this if you wanted to unify the storage platform instead of having it split up. It will obviously be slower than memcached or redis.

---

A completely different approach could be using Lucene/Solr to index your logs. This has a lot of nice features out of the box for searching.